# How to create Duplicate buttons for Action Column in Grid Magento2?

Tags: magento2, grid

I am trying to add duplicate button to action column, but it is not working. How to handle this. Please help me[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your UI Compoenent Grid add `actionColumn` in `columns` tag

```
 <actionsColumn name="actions" class = "TheRealHunzik\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Sizechart\Column\Action">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
```

Now in You `TheRealHunzik\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Sizechart\Column\Action.php` file add like this

```
<?php

namespace TheRealHunzik\ModuleName\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Action extends Column
{
    /** Url path */
    const ROW_EDIT_URL = 'therealhunzik_modulename/modulename/addrow';
    const ROW_DUPLICATE_URL = 'therealhunzik_modulename/modulename/duplicate';
    /** @var UrlInterface */
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $_editUrl;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface   $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlInterface       $urlBuilder
     * @param array              $components
     * @param array              $data
     * @param string             $editUrl
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = [],
        $editUrl = self::ROW_EDIT_URL,
        $duplicateUrl = self::ROW_DUPLICATE_URL
    ) {
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_editUrl = $editUrl;
        $this->_duplicateUrl = $duplicateUrl;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source.
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $name = $this->getData('name');
                if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                    $item[$name]['edit'] = [
                        'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            $this->_editUrl,
                            ['id' => $item['entity_id']]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Edit'),
                    ];
                    $item[$name]['suplicate'] = [
                        'href' => $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(
                            $this->_duplicateUrl,
                            ['id' => $item['entity_id']]
                        ),
                        'label' => __('Duplicate'),
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Now you have to add Controller and Write code to Duplicate specific Item

Comment: I got it, Thank you!

Comment: please mark answer so it might help others